# URL Rewrite with and without trailing slash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm busy with making a website multi-language. The language selection I want with the url. So for example:

```
https://www.website.com/spain/en/
```

But I also want it to work with out the trailing slash at the end, so like this:

```
https://www.website.com/spain/en
```

This is the re-write rule I have now. It works fine, but without the trailing slash it gives a 404 page not found.

```
RewriteRule ^spain/en/$ /index.php?country=spain&language=en&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Even a 301 redirect would maybe be ok.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your rule only applies if there *is* a trailing slash, so you can modify it to make it optional. The following should work:

```
RewriteRule ^spain/en/?$ /index.php?country=spain&language=en&%{QUERY_STRING}
```